# boost mpl string

Tags: c++, boost, character, boost-mpl

Hi in boost mpl documentation I have discovered mpl::string and the following example:

```
typedef mpl::string<'hell','o wo','rld'> hello;
```

I'm a little bit surprised because I thought that in C or C++ we can't have more than one character between the character **'** ?

Is it normal and valid ?

Comment: Just ab FYI. This (http://cpp-next.com/archive/2012/10/using-strings-in-c-template-metaprograms/) article has a better solution if you have c++11 available.

Comment: That link is now dead :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is valid C++. From any existing C++ standard, section [lex.conn]:

> An ordinary character literal that contains more than one *c-char* is a *multicharacter literal*. A multicharacter literal has type `int` and implementation-defined value.

Comment: oh well that's why we can't have 5 characters between '